# What scaling really means mathematically?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

I was reading [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola#:%7E:text=A%20parabola%20is%20a%20set,of%20symmetry%20of%20the%20parabola.) article on wikipedia regarding parabolas where it said :

> "*Any parabola can be repositioned and rescaled to fit exactly on any other parabola—that is, all parabolas are geometrically similar.*"

I have learnt similarities of triangles which is that corresponding sides have a fixed ratio. And I have an intuition of scaling a line segment , which is something like pulling it along it's length to increase/decrease it's length.
But how do we define **scaling** mathematically for more complex shapes like parabolas , rectangles etc ? I am looking for both geometrical and an algebraic definition to learn about it.

Comment: For y=f(x) kinds of formulas, like a parabola $y=x^2$, scaling is literally just multiplying by a scalar, like a real number. It is equivalent to put one in front of the $x$ or its inverse in front of $y$ in the equation. Just like shifting the parabola up is adding a scalar to the $y$ side, and shifting left/right is adding a number to $x$ variable, like $y-2=3(x-3)^2$ shifts the parabola down 2, to the right 3, and stretches it 3x tall. You want to look up affine transforms, ultimately.

Comment: As in the article, $(x,y)\to (ax,ay)$.

Comment: @JohnDouma Thanks. But scaling is something I expected related to length and have a more like geometrical definition. However this change of variable is of scaling co-ordinates and not length.

Comment: Two geometric figures $f$, $f'$ are similar if there is a bijective mapping that to every point $A$ of $f$ assigns a point $A'$ of $f'$, such that if $A$, $B$ are two points in $f$ and $A'$, $B'$ their images in $f'$, then $A'B'=kAB$, where $k$ is a fixed positive constant, called "scale factor".

Comment: @An_Elephant If $(1, 0)$ and $(2,0)$ go to $(5,0)$ and $(10,0)$ respectively, how does the length of the segment between them change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One might ask the same question even about "congruence": perhaps one has an intuition about congruence of line segments (same length); or congruence of triangles; what does it mean for parabolas to be congruent?

And one might extend this: What does it mean for any two shapes in the Euclidean plane to be similar? Or to be congruent?

There is a common answer to both of these questions. There is a group of *similarity transformations* that acts on the plane, and two objects are similar if and only if there exists a similarity transformation taking one object to the other. Also, there is also a group of *rigid motions* that acts on the plane, and two objects are congruent if and only if there  exists a rigid motion taking one object to the other.

Part of the reason that I brought rigid motions in to this answer is that they are easier to describe first, before describing similarity transformations. In Cartesian coordinates, a rigid motion is any function of the form
\begin{align*}
f(x,y) &= (ax+by+e,cx+dy+f), \quad a,b,c,d,e,f \in \mathbb R \\
       &= (x,y) \cdot \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} a & c \\ b & d \end{pmatrix}}_M + (e,f)
\end{align*}
where the matrix $M$ satisfies the restriction that it is *orthonormal* meaning that it satisfies $MM^T = \text{Id}$ (here I'm assuming a bit of linear algebra; if you like you can think of $M$ more intuitively as either a rotational transformation centered on the origin or a reflection transformation across a line that passes through the origin).

There is now a kind of meta theorem: two Euclidean objects $A,B \subset \mathbb R^2$ are congruent if and only if there exists a rigid motion $f$ such that $f(A)=B$. You can check special cases of this metatheorem for yourself; here are some examples. When $A,B$ are two line segments, congruence is equivalent to having the same length. When $A,B$ are triangles, congruence is equivalent to the triple of side lengths being the same for $A$ as for $B$; this is essentially the SSS axiom of classical Euclidean geometry. In the end once you've exhausted proofs for "classical" cases of congruence (e.g. line segments; triangles), then you make up your mind to define *general* congruence in the same way using rigid motions.

On to similarity transformations. The key idea is that a scalar multiplication function $(x,y) \mapsto (sx,sy)$ has a useful global effect: *all* lengths of *all* objects are multiplied by the same factor, that factor being $|s|$ (we assume $s \ne 0$).

In Cartesian coordinates, a similarity transformation is any function of the form
\begin{align*}
g(x,y) &= s(ax+by+e,cx+dy+f), \quad s,a,b,c,d,e,f \in \mathbb R \\
  &= s \biggl((x,y) \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} a & c \\ b & d \end{pmatrix}}_M + (e,f)\biggr)
\end{align*}
such that $s \ne 0$ and the matrix $M = \begin{pmatrix} a & c \\ b & d \end{pmatrix}$ is orthonormal. To put this another way a similarity transformation $g$ is any transformation that can be written as the composition of a rigid motion of $\mathbb R^2$ and a scalar multiplication function on $\mathbb R^2$.

Using this notion, you can prove many special cases: that any two line segments are similar, and any two triangles whose side-length triples are in proportion to each other are similar, and you can prove that any two squares are similar, and that any two parabolas are similar. And again you turn this into a definition: similarity of two objects in the Euclidean plane is *defined* by the requirement that there is a similarity transformation taking one to the other.

To summarize, similarity is defined in one unified way: two objects of the plane are similar of there exists a similarity transformation -- meaning a rigid motion composed with a scalar multiplication -- that takes one object to the other.

Comment: Thanks. Even though I can't understand much of it , but It feels like this answer gives a rigourous approach.

Answer (score 0):

**Wikipedia citation:** "The graph of a quadratic function $y = ax^2 + bx + c$ is a parabola if $a ≠ 0$, and, conversely, a parabola is the graph of a quadratic function if its axis is parallel to the y-axis."

**Comment:** If $y:=ax^2+bx+c$ is the equation defining your parabola you may "complete the square" to get the following equation:

$$ y=ax^2+bx+c=a(x^2+\frac{b}{a}x+ (\frac{b}{2a})^2 - (\frac{b}{2a})^2) + c = $$

$$ a(x+\frac{b}{2a})^2 + \frac{4ac-b^2}{4a}  :=a(x-\alpha)^2 + \beta .$$

You get the "new equation"

$$ y=a(x-\alpha)^2 + \beta $$

and when you rewrite this equation to get

$$ y-\beta =a(x-\alpha)^2$$

you may choose "new variables"  $u:=y-\beta, v:=x-\alpha$ to get the equation

$$u=av^2$$

**Your comment:** "But how do we define scaling mathematically for more complex shapes like parabolas , rectangles etc ? I am looking for both geometrical and an algebraic definition to learn about it."

**Anwer:** Im unsure what you mean when you say "scaling", but if the number $a$
in the equation is a positive real number you may write $a:=\gamma^2$ and write

$$ u:=(\gamma v)^2$$

and let $w:=\gamma v$ to get the equation

$$ u=w^2.$$

If $a$ is negative you get

$$y=-w^2.$$

Hence  - up to a variable change and scaling in the above sense - it follows any parabola is on the form $y=x^2$ or $y=-x^2$.

**Question:** "I have learnt similarities of triangles which is that corresponding sides have a fixed ratio. And I have an intuition of scaling a line segment , which is something like pulling it along it's length to increase/decrease it's length. But how do we define scaling mathematically for more complex shapes like parabolas , rectangles etc ? I am looking for both geometrical and an algebraic definition to learn about it."

**Answer:** We made two changes of variables above: $u:=y-\beta, w:=\gamma(x-\alpha)$ and this gives the following classification: A parabola is given by one of the formulas:  $u=w^2$ or $u=-w^2$.

Answer (score 0):

You can scale *any* relation horizontally by replacing every occurrence of $x$ with $(ax)$, and it will shrink horizontally by a factor of $a$ (to grow, use numbers between 0 and 1).  You can scale *any* relation vertically by replacing every occurrence of $y$ with $(by)$, and it will shrink vertically by a factor of $b$.

You can reposition *any* relation horizontally by replacing every occurrence of $x$ with $(x - c)$, where $c$ is the amount that you want to move the graph to the *right*.  You can reposition *any* relation vertically by replacing every occurrence of $y$ with $(y - d)$, where $d$ is the amount that you want to move the graph *up*.

Example: Take the graph of $\sin(xy) = x^2$.  You can shift it to the right by the following: $\sin((x - 2)y) = (x - 2)^2$.

Comment: For more on this, you might want to see my article, "Reviving the Relational View of Mathematics".  https://mindmatters.ai/2022/06/reviving-the-relational-view-of-mathematics/